# UIViewController and data receiving issue with Navigation stack

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am developing one navigation based application. All data required for each screen are getting downladed from webserver. I am starting downloading in viewDidLoad method. ALl downloadinh is happening asynchroniously and respective viewcontroller will receive data through delegate pattern. Now my question is in case new viewcontroller is getting pushed on navigation stack or current view controller is getting popped off so fast before data will get received, how we will handle this situation? We do not want to block UI so user can move back or forward. I used notification mechanism to detect particular view controller (one who receive data ) is alive or not , but it seems like not a concrete solution. So basically I want to detect receiver is appropriate for receiving downloaded data before I make a call to its delegate method.
Any pointer related to it is highly appreciable.

Thanks!
Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

I think the dataSource pattern is more appropriate.

1) Create a datasource (singleton or attached in your app delegate)

2) Implement a method dataWithPredicate: (or just data)

3) Notify your viewController (with NSNotificationCenter) when a data is updated

4) Reload data from the controller (with dataWithPredicate: call)

Another way is to use core data for that. CoreData generate all the notification and do the job for you.